# scaling triple Venn diagram in R with VennDiagram package

Tags: r, venn-diagram

Does anyone know how to get the R package VennDiagram to scale the circles of a Venn diagram containing 3 intersecting sets according to set size?

I can achieve such scaling with the venneular package, but I find this a bit limited in terms of other graphical options compared to VennDiagram.

The VennDiagram package documentation suggests setting the argument 'scaled' to TRUE ought to do the trick, but I find this produces 3 circles of equal size.

The package documentation does cryptically suggest that the scaled argument may only work for certain diagrams:

```
?draw.triple.venn
```

reveals:

scaled:
"Boolean indicating whether to scale circle sizes in certain Euler diagrams according to set    sizes or not"

and

```
?venn.diagram

#Argument Venn Sizes    Class    Description
#scaled    2, 3         logical  Enable scaling for two-set and certain three-set Euler diagrams.
```

A toy example of my code:

```
require(VennDiagram)

venn.plot <- draw.triple.venn(
    area1 = 70,
    area2 = 250,
    area3 = 500,
    n12 = 30,
    n23 = 60,
    n13 = 10,
    n123 = 5,
    category = c("C1", "C2", "C3"),
    fill = c("blue", "red", "green"),
    scaled=TRUE)

tiff(filename = "test.tiff", compression = "none",type = "quartz",antialias = "none")
grid.draw(venn.plot)
dev.off()
```

Similarly this code using the 'venn.diagram' function doesn't produce the required scaling:

```
venn.diagram(x=list(A=c(1:15,16:20), B=c(6:15,21:30,100:150), C=c(11:30,200:300)),
         filename="test.tiff",
         fill = c("blue", "yellow", "red"), scaled=TRUE)
```

Thanks v.much

Jim

Answer (score 6):

So to answer my own question:
for certain configurations it is mathematically impossible to create a
scaled 3-way Venn using circles.

Comment: on Biostars there is a similar thread saying it is impossible. With elipses, it is possible. Did you find a way to draw it using R?

Answer (score 5):

General scaling for three-set Venn diagrams are disabled due to potentially misleading visual representation of the data

Please try to use the following two tools,

http://bioinformatics.psb.ugent.be/webtools/Venn/
http://bioinfogp.cnb.csic.es/tools/venny/index.html

And to your question, please read the following notes:

the key point is to set ***overrideTriple*** in draw.triple.venn

Euler diagrams are drawn for 19 special cases if euler.d == TRUE. Certain Euler diagrams make use of the scaled, sep.dist, or offset arguments specific to two-set Venn diagrams where appropriate. The function defaults to placing the three circles in a triangular arrangement with two sets on top and one set below. The circles correspond to area1, area2 and area3 in a clockwise fashion with area1 on the top left. **N.B. General scaling for three-set Venn diagrams are disabled due to potentially misleading visual representation of the data. To re-enable, assign any value to variable *overrideTriple***

http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/VennDiagram/VennDiagram.pdf

Comment: I've tried setting this variable and it does not work. I ran the example from the original question with and without overrideTriple (I set it to TRUE) and the output was the same.

Comment: The trick is how the 'overrideTriple=T' variable is to be set ... namely before the 'draw.triple.venn' call - see answer by @atongsa. Btw, this also seems to work for the more general 'venn.diagram' call in the {VennDiagram} package.

Comment: Huh?? It seems more misleading to not scale the circles.  Anyways, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 4):

My solution:

```
overrideTriple=T
draw.triple.venn(9, 20, 30, 2, 10, 3, 2, category =
               rep("", 3), rotation = 1, reverse = FALSE, euler.d = F, scaled = F)
```

Comment: That solved it for me! The trick was how the 'overrideTriple=T' variable is to be set ... namely before the 'draw.triple.venn' call. Btw, this also seems to work for the more general 'venn.diagram' call in the {VennDiagram} package.

Answer (score 1):

I use [Vennerable](https://r-forge.r-project.org/projects/vennerable/) instead. Reading data into the Venn-object is somewhat complicated but it generates weighted/scaled three-set diagrams + graphic options.

Answer (score 1):

If you would consider a different approach, we have developed the nVennR package with other shapes to convey region sizes.

```
mySVG <- plotVenn(list(A=c(1:15,16:20)), list(B=c(6:15,21:30,100:150)), list(C=c(11:30,200:300)))
```

[Quasi-proportional Venn diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvTug.png)

This R package is preliminary, and the options for output control are very limited. We are working on a new version with the feedback we are getting. There is also a [Web version](http://degradome.uniovi.es/cgi-bin/nVenn/nvenn.cgi) with more options, and the output can always be edited with external tools like Inkscape.