# scaled triple Venn diagram in R with VennDiagram

Tags: r, venn-diagram

Do you know why the following code cannot creat scaled Venn Diagram?

```
library("VennDiagram")
area1=138
area2=590
area3=909
n12=123
n13=121
n23=528
n123=119
draw.triple.venn(area1,area2,area3,n12,n23,n13,n123,category=c("GSE35069","GSE41169","GSE42861"),col=2:4,fill=2:4,lwd=2,ind=FALSE,list.order=1:3,scale=T,euler.d=TRUE)
```

Do you have any other choice to get scale triple Venn Diagram for such situation?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to generate the graph removing `ind=FALSE` from your same code.

Also, ind is used for that as it reads in the `?draw.triple.venn` help page

> Boolean indicating whether the function is to automatically draw the
>   diagram before returning the gList object or not

[image]

Also, you should check your code. It reads "cale=T" instead of "scale=T". It happens to me that I miss a letter or a comma somewhere very often.
The problem with scale it's not solved by the correct spelling. I was looking for the answer and found that this question has been already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11727068/scaling-triple-venn-diagram-in-r-with-venndiagram-package)